# Socket - Packets separated once send to server

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to send sockets to a server using Java:

```
_socket   = new Socket(host, port);
_writer   = new DataOutputStream(_socket.getOutputStream());

public void send(String data){
    _writer.writeBytes( data );
    _writer.flush();
}
```

I want to send data as a same Packet, and sometimes it's divide into multiples one. I don't know if it's clear enough, I'm missing some vocabulary.

If I send:

> "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

The server can possibly receive the data into 3 packets :

1. `"0123456"`
2. `"789abcdefghijklmno"`
3. `"pqrstuvwxyz"`

Is there a way to don't separate the data you send into multiple packets ?

---

`BufferedOutputStream` seems to fix the problem.

Comment: What's the problem with concatenating it on the other side?

Comment: I don't own the server I want to connect.

Comment: "send sockets to a server"?  Do you know how any of this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BufferedOutputStream` seems to fix the problem.

Comment: That way you get it all in one piece, because `BufferedOutputStream` will send the data with one system call, and in most practical environments such a short piece of data will be delivered in one packet of the underlying protocol (like IP). But this is depending on unspecified behaviour, depending on how things work in practice *in some specfic situation*. It's asking for things to break unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I didn't know that `Sockets` divided up data, but I imagine it's to be expected. One option you've got is simply to have a character or combination of characters to signify the end of a transmission. ie:

```
String data = "Hello there, this is a long packet";
String delimiter = "ENDOFPACKET"; // Obviously, it will need to be more complex.

String packet = data + delimiter;
send(packet);
```

In your reader, instead of processing every packet, simply concatenate to a string until the `delimiter` value is found.

Comment: I don't own the server I want to connect so it's not possible :(

Comment: Riight. And this server isn't programmed to deal with split up packets?

Comment: No, each packets have a 2 bytes header with a specific length, if the packet isn't complete the server detect it as a corrupted data.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps setting a buffer size would help:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSendBufferSize%28int%29

I haven't tried this option, though. I must admit I would expect the buffer to be more than just a dozen of bytes like in your case.

Comment: I just check setSendBufferSize, it don't seems to work as expected. Same result by setting to 2*1024.

Answer (score 0):

I made some test and it works perfect in my case. I receive at the other side the whole data in just one read.

I use this function:

```
public void send(String data)
{
   try
   {
       socket.getOutputStream().write(data.getBytes());
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
   }
}
```

I think even if you use 3 reads to get the data it doesn't necessarily means you received 3 packets, may be 1, 2 or even more than 3. It's hard to answer the question properly without knowing how the server reads the data. For example, if I have 200 bytes in the queue and I read in a 50 bytes buffer then I need 4 reads to get the data. This is pretty obvious, but worth mentioning.

Comment: I have to use DataOutputStream(), the OutputStream has some problems keeping the data integrity : Client send (long)2000000, server receive (long)1982271. About the packets received by server, I capture it using a packet sniffer (WPE or RPE), here I can see the packet I sent split into two packets.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about; I use client/server applications with OutputStream and never get into that problem of long 200000 to long 1982271. And in this particular case you are sending a String, so it does nothing to deal with long and integers. By the way, what device are you using for the client?

Answer (score 0):

This is basic feature of stream protocols, such as TCP/IP or local sockets: it is a stream of bytes guaranteed to be delivered in correct order, and that's it, no packet boundaries.

So you need your own protocol to separate the packets. There are two basic ways.

First, you can have a have special byte or byte sequence, such as simple newline or byte 0 in text stream, which marks end of message.

Second, you can have a packet header, which can be as simple as 32 bit raw binary number, usually in network byte order, telling size of message, followed by that many bytes of actual message data. This works well with binary data.

Or use a hybrid approach: first read a line of text header, ending at next newline, which you parse as text data, and which includes length. Then read that many bytes of raw binary data, then read next header line as text and so on. This is easier to debug, when you can visually see if your server and client stay in sync, and it is also easy to expand, because header is not of fixed size.